# Printing list elements on separate lines in Python

Tags: python

When I try this code:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

I get an output like:

```
['.', '/usr/bin', '/home/student/Desktop', '/home/student/my_modules', '/usr/lib/pyth
on2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/pyth
on2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-pack
ages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/
usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/
python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/p
ython2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

How can I print each element of the list on a separate line, like so?

```
/usr/bin
/home/student/Desktop
/home/student/my_modules
```

Answer (score 232):

```
print("\n".join(sys.path))
```

(The outer parentheses are included for Python 3 compatibility and are usually omitted in Python 2.)

Comment: I know, It doesn't matter for that sized list, but just printing inside a for loop is consumes less memory and slightly simplier than this.

Comment: How would you do it in a for loop?

Comment: @Larry: `for line in sys.path: print line`

Comment: py3: `f = lambda *x: null; f( *( print( x ) for x in sys.path ) )` -- just joking...

Answer (score 100):

Use the print function (Python 3.x) or import it (Python 2.6+):

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(*sys.path, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This answer is best when printing a list containing non-string elements.

Answer (score 30):

Use the [splat operator (`*`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call).

By default, `print` prints arguments separated by space. Use `sep` argument to specify the delimiter:

```
print(*sys.path, sep="\n")
```

Comment: How is that different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168360/6045800) answer from 2011?

Answer (score 24):

Another good option for handling this kind of option is the `pprint` module, which (among other things) pretty prints long lists with one element per line:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webkit-1.0']
>>>
```

Comment: if `a = [1,3,5]`, then that line will only print this array in one line... is there a guaranteed way for `pprint` to print it on separate lines?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 `pprint.pprint(x,width=max([len(str(s)) for s in x])+3)`

Answer (score 19):

```
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

Comment: Caution: do not ever try this with a notebook controlled by `papermill`! Extremely inefficient approach, and if you overuse it (e.g. put it in hundreds of cells), `papermill` will process the notebook about 10 times slower than without all these loops. You may also get `Timeout waiting for IOPub output` and `papermill: Autosave too slow` errors.

Comment: @mirekphd, do you know what about this breaks papermill?

Comment: I can only speculate as for the reasons... the things I do know is that this used to work fine before January 10 and that downgrading all libraries (whole containers) or changing the browser or switching to Lab does not help. What did help was switching to a one-liner based on `join` (it restored `papermill` speeds equivalent to no printing).

Answer (score 9):

Sven Marnach's answer is pretty much it, but has one generality issue... It will fail if the list being printed doesn't just contain strings.

So, the more general answer to "How to print out a list with elements separated by newlines"...

```
print '\n'.join([ str(myelement) for myelement in mylist ])
```

Then again, the print function approach JBernardo points out is superior.  If you can, using the print function instead of the print statement is almost always a good idea.

Comment: You should avoid using list comprehension where a generator expression can be used, and you can definitely use one here. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35837818/3375713). You will get more useful links in that answer, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ not true in this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/5320906

Comment: @snakecharmerb it's good to know. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more general solution based on `join`, that works even for `pandas.Timestamp`:

`print("\n".join(map(str, my_list)))`

Answer (score 2):

For printing list elements on separate lines, you can use:

```
files = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt']
for i in range(len(files)): print(files[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

sys.path returns the list of paths

[ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

> sys.path

A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable **PYTHONPATH**, plus an installation-dependent default.

As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of **PYTHONPATH**.

```
import sys
dirs=sys.path
for path in dirs:
   print(path)
```

or you can print only first path by

`print(dir[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn your list into a numpy array of size `len(sys.path)`

```
print(np.array(sys.path).reshape(-1,1))
```

outputs:

```
[['.']
 ['/usr/bin']
 ['/home/student/Desktop']
 ['/home/student/my_modules']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk']
 ['/usr/lib/pyton2.6/lib-old']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload']
 ['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10']
 ['/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
 ['/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
 ['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']]
```