# How to extract parameters from a list and pass them to a function call

Tags: python, list, argument-unpacking

What is a good, brief way to extract items from a list and pass them as parameters to a function call, such as in the example below?

Example:

```
def add(a,b,c,d,e):
    print(a,b,c,d,e)

x=(1,2,3,4,5)

add(magic_function(x))
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can unpack a tuple or a list into positional arguments using a star.

```
def add(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

x = (1, 2, 3)
add(*x)
```

Similarly, you can use double star to unpack a dict into keyword arguments.

```
x = { 'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }
add(**x)
```

Answer (score 17):

I think you mean the `*` [unpacking operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> def add(a,b,c,d,e):
...    print(a,b,c,d,e)
...
>>> add(*l)
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `*` operator. So `add(*x)` would do what you want.

See this other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) for more information.