# Using sys.argv for input through Terminal

Tags: python, input, terminal, sys

I wrote a Python script that I am now trying to get to run via the command line. It consists of a function that takes one obligatory and a few optional arguments.

`def main(input_folder, iterations = 1000, probability_cutoff = - 40 , threshold = 10): ...`

Now I am trying to make it executable through the command line like so:

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])`

This works well as long as I put in only one argument; but I don't know how to accept the additional, optional input that `sys.argv` delivers as a list.

- Is there a simple way of doing this with this approach?
- Or is it necessary to use an additional module such as
  [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?
- I tried feeding keyword arguments into the function as well but
  couldn't make that work either - is that a feasible approach?

I am working with Python 2.7 on a Mac. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm going to say this is a duplicate of [How to extract parameters from a list and pass them to a function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call) because that is the mechanism you are asking for (as well as `[1:]` to skip the first item of argv)

Comment: that is probably true but I did not find that one as I was not using the right search terms. Should I delete this one?

Comment: not at all, anyone else trying to unpack `sys.argv` (like you) but doesn't use the right search terms to find the relevant question (like you) will find this question and it will help them.

Comment: I would like to note however that all the elements of `sys.argv` are strings so when you do  `main(*sys.argv[1:])` like in the accepted answer you will need to parse the numbers yourself.

Comment: yes I just added int() to whenever they are used. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yeah, just reminding you since your default values are already integers so any conversions would be redundant (not a problem but you might forget why conversions are needed)

Comment: Type conversion is another reason I prefer argparse, @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use argparse, because it gives you nice error handling, converts strings to ints or open files, and clearly documents the options. However, this should do what you want:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```