# Calling Python function with set of parameters from variable

Tags: python

In my Python script I call this function a few times

```
write2db(int(pocnr), larm1, tid, label1, q1, x, y, lat, long, radio)
```

I want to be able to have the set of variables in one variable.

Should look like this

write2db(myargs)

So when I make a change to list of args I don't have to do it in more than one place. I have tried a few things but so far no luck. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: `write2db(*myargs)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract parameters from a list and pass them to a function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call)

Comment: i feel stupid but i dont understand all the answers. To clear the question a bit. How do I define the myargs? I've tried to do it global as myargs = (int(pocnr), larm1, tid, label1, q1, x, y, lat, long, radio) but then the variables are not defined yet.

Comment: There is an explicit example by denvaar. Also, **do not post code in comments. Why do you expect people to read your code in a comment, especially for python, where indentation is important?**

Comment: Sorry and you don't need to shout on a beginner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*args` or `**kwargs`. The names `args` and `kwargs` don't actually matter, but its the `*` and `**` that does the trick. Basically, `*` will unpack a list, and similarly, `**` will unpack a dict.

`*args` is just a list of values in the same order as where you defined your function.

eg.

```
args = [23, 6, 2, "label", 5, 25, 21, 343.22, 111.34, 2]
write2db(*args)
```

`**kwargs` is a key-value mapping (python dict) of argument names to argument values

eg.

```
kwargs = {
    'pocnr': 23,
    'larm1': 21,
    # ... etc.
}
write2db(**kwargs)
```

Comment: So you think args = [int(pocnr), larm1, tid, label1, q1, x, y, lat, long, radio] will do the trick?

Comment: It did! Thanks alot. Now i can make my code more clean and easier to admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a namedtuple with each of those arguments, then get the arguments out by name inside of the function.

Or you could just use variable length argument *args, and then inside your function:

```
    for arg in args:
        # do something with arg
```

Comment: You can just pass `f(*args)`. No need to change any definitions.