# Don't understand cause of "IndexError: tuple index out of range" when formatting string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I looked at similar questions having this `IndexError` but didn't find an explanation to my case. Can someone explain why I get the error?

The following code

```
mySF2[0]=['000browser', '1', 'Floor', '0.92', '1.74', 'con', 'None']

insertfmt = ' '.join([
"INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable_{}_name (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)",  
"VALUES ({}, {}, NULLIF({},'None')::decimal, NULLIF({},'None')::decimal, {}, NULLIF({},'None')::int)"
         ])

insertfmt.format(mySF2[0])
```

Gives this error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

However, I count 7 placeholders (i.e. curly brackets {}) and 7 items to input. Why the error then?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call

Comment: `'{}{}'.format([1,2])` doesn't work.  You need to do `'{}{}'.format(*[1,2])` to expand the `[1,2]`.  This is the same as `'{}{}'.format(1,2)`

Comment: Also using string formatting to construct queries is inherently unsafe - far better to use the proper SQL interface praceholder function (ie. a single `?` character and passing the tuple as an extra parameter to the execute or executemany method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`str.format()` accepts a variable number of arguments corresponding to the number of "holes" in your format string. In your case, you are passing in a single argument (a list) to `.format()`, which causes an error because it expects seven arguments.

To pass in an array to a function as separate arguments, you need to use the `*` operator like so:

```
insertfmt.format(*mySF2[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation was clear and the correction worked perfectly. If I may, I have a follow-up question. Is there a way to specify that some of the arguments (e.g. 'Floor') should remain strings, i.e. including the single quotes? In the current form, all arguments are stripped of the quotes, which hinders the SQL syntax. I looked up the doc of .format but didn't find a solution :/

Comment: To directly answer your question: if you are absolutely sure that your string won't contain any special characters such as an escaped single quote, you can use the `repr()` function to print out the Python representation of the object. E.g. `repr('Floor') == "'Floor'"`.

However, I'd like to point out that inserting strings into a format string representing a SQL query like you are is prone to SQL injection attacks. I'd highly advise that you use a library that safely escapes parameters into SQL statements so that malicious inputs cannot execute arbitrary SQL statements.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I take note of your warning, though as now it is mainly for personal use it should be fine. More concretely, I solved the issue by placing a few {!r} where needed.

Comment: how to expand dicts instead of lists?

Comment: To expand dicts, use `**` instead of `*`.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue while trying to plot with `seaborn` and annotations.  I was using

```
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="{.0%}")
```

Removing the braces fixed it :

```
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt=".0%")
```