# While using recursion, list won't add any new elements

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am asked to define a function that takes in a list and returns another list, all that while using recursion. However when I run the else command and I print the `lst_` , the output shows that on every run the list contains a single element, instead of having the doubles added one by one.Also I try not to use `append()` Thoughts?

```
def double(lst, lst_ = []):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list;
    returns : another list with lst's elements doubled
    """
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst_
    else:
        lst[0] = int(lst[0]) + int(lst[0])
        lst_ = lst_ + lst[0:1]            
        print(lst_)
        return double(lst[1:])

print(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

This is the output

```
[2]
[4]
[6]
[8]
[10]
[12]
[14]
[16]
[]
```

Comment: Write exactly what you need. With output and input data.

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to return a copy without modifying the original, I would not recommend using the mutable default argument.

Instead,

```
def double(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    return [2*lst[0], *double(lst[1:])] # [2*lst[0]] + double(lst[1:])
```

The recursive case must return a fresh list, and the base case will check for, and return an empty list.

```
lst1 = double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) 
print(lst1)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

---

If you want to have a little fun, you can attempt a generator-based recursive solution using `yield from` (generator delegation):

```
def double(lst):
    if lst:
        yield 2*lst[0]
        yield from double(lst[1:])

lst = list(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) )
print(lst)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def double(lst, lst_ = []):
  if len(lst) == 0:
    return lst_
  else:
    lst[0] = int(lst[0]) + int(lst[0])
    lst_.extend(lst[:1])
    return double(lst[1:])

print(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))

#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without using `append()` ?

Comment: This `for item in lst[0:1]:` is unnecessary. You can directly add to list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` on list to add elements at the end:

```
def double(lst, lst_ = []):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list;
    returns : another list with lst's elements doubled
    """
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst_
    else:
        lst[0] += lst[0]
        lst_.append(lst[0])          
        return double(lst[1:])

print(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

Also, note that this line `lst[0] = int(lst[0]) + int(lst[0])` in you code can be shortened to `lst[0] += lst[0]`, because you are dealing with integers only and that explicit casting is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use append(). Then you can use this solution:

```
def double(lst, lst_ = []):
    if not lst:
        return lst_
    else:
        return [lst[0] * 2 , *double(lst[1:])]

print(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

The output will be : `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]`

Just in case you are wondering with the *double(lst[1:]) call: *[] is used for unpacking argument list. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call)
If you call without the * you will get an output like:

```
[2, [4, [6, [8, [10, [12, [14, [16, []]]]]]]]]
```

Another easy solution will be:

```
def double(lst, lst_ = []):
    if not lst:
        return lst_
    else:
        lst[0] = lst[0] * 2
        lst_ = lst_.append(lst[0])
        return double(lst[1:])

print(double([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```