# How to get parameters from data list with 'for' cycle

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a Micropython program and i have a question about one piece of code. This code is no different from regular Python, it doesn't need specific micropython libraries.

Question itself:

Funсtion 'oled.text' takes three parameters. One is string and two other are coordinates(int). How do I transfer values from list so they become parameters?  Should i create 'for' cycle inside the function? If the answer is yes, how should i do it?

Sorry for my English, it not my native language

```
x = 6
list = {
    ('bad', 0, 0),
    ('good', 10, 10),
    ('ugly', 20, 20),
    ('bullets:', 5, 30),
    (str(x), 70, 30)
    }
for i in list:
    oled.text(i[0], i[1], i[2])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract parameters from a list and pass them to a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527849/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-list-and-pass-them-to-a-function-call)

Comment: you want to pass all list to your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `list` should be created using squared bracket `[]` instead of curly bracket `{}` used by `set` and `dictionary`.

For your question you should be able to achieve it using the code snippet as follow

```
for i in list:
    function(*i)
```

The `*` operator unpacks the tuple in the list and provides it as parameter for the function

Comment: It's alive! IT'S ALIVE! Thank you!:)