# how to use format in python iteratively?

Tags: python, format, iteration, logic, sat

im currently writing a program which requires me to have a logical formula and then try every combination of True and False on that logical formula. Currently I have some code which creates a logical formula in the form : `({1} or not {2} or not {5} )and (not {1} or {6} )and (not {2} or not {3} )and ({3} or not {4} )and (not {4} or {5} or not {6} )` where the numbers need to be swapped out for every combination of true and false. The combos of true and false i work out using this line `combos= product([True,False],repeat = no_variables)`. I currently have this code to attempt to do this:

```
for i in combos:
    for j in range (no_variables):
            k=j+1 //as the variables in the string do not start at 0
            print(formulastring.format(k = i[j]))
```

however it doesn't work and returns this error:

```
print(formulastring.format(k = i[j]))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: How does you formulastring look like?

Comment: it is shown in the text above the code it is the logical formula @RishabhKumar

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are giving a format string that looks for positional arguments (`{0}`, `{1}`, etc), but you call your format function with keyword arguments (`k=...`)

You need to either change your format string to accept keyword arguments, like: `{k}` instead of `{0}`,

Or, change the way you pass the arguments, so call it like `.format(i[j], ...)`. Remember, your format string expects 7 arguments.

Demonstration:

```
# Positional
"{0} {1} {2}".format(3, 423, 12)
# Output: '3 423 12'

# Keyword
"{a} {b} {c}".format(a=3, b=423, c=12)
# Output: '3 423 12'
```

---

Now applying this to your problem:

```
formulastring = "({1} or not {2} or not {5} )and (not {1} or {6} )and (not {2} or not {3} )and ({3} or not {4} )and (not {4} or {5} or not {6} )"
no_variables = 7 # Judging from this particular formatstring

combos= product([True,False],repeat = no_variables)
# Each element of combos is a 7-element tuple

for values in combos:
    # values is a tuple containing no_variables booleans
    # *values unpacks the tuple and passes it as positional arguments to format()
    print(formulastring.format(*values))
```

This gives the output you expect.

Comment: but k changes from 0 to 6 with each iteration. The overall code is meant to work for any logical formula so I am not able to hard code in exactly how many variables there would be as it may change for each formula

Comment: I'm adding to my answer. Hold tight

Comment: I cannot use poisitional as some variables are repeated in the formula and I cant do keyword as I cannot hard code the variables from before.

Comment: You can pass a list as positional arguments by [unpacking it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527889/843953). I'm editing my answer to include an example

Comment: Does this work even though I have variables being used more than one in the formal string so they would have to be replaced with the same variable ? As it does not work and returns `    print(formulastring.format(*values))
IndexError: Replacement index 6 out of range for positional args tuple` this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228859/discussion-between-pranav-hosangadi-and-userj).

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

combos = list(itertools.product([False, True], repeat=6))

test = f'({1} or not {2} or not {5}) and (not {1} or {6})and (not {2} or not {3} )and ({3} or not {4} )and (not {4} or {5} or not {6} )'

results = []
for combo in combos:
    cur = test
    for idx, val in enumerate(combo):
        cur = cur.replace(str(idx+1), str(val))
        
    results.append(eval(cur))
```

Comment: what does the f in test mean ?

Comment: and is 'results' the overall truth assignment obtained by each combo ?

Comment: It is an f-string, basically python will evaluate whatever is in {} brackets, so in this case, test just ends up with a 1, 2, 3, etcc in those spots. You could remove the {} brackets and the string wouldn't change. Right, results contains True or False for each combo in combos.

Comment: I had a couple bugs that I fixed. Should work now!