# Printing data from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, printing

I have got data to print. I create list but I can't print it. My list is:

```
NEW_2 = [['ID', 'FK'], ['1', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['5', '3'], ['6', '2']]
```

And after print it should be like that:

```
ID  FK
1   1
2   1
5   3
6   2
```

After all, I have to save that to the file, that will looks like that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please see any python tutorial that covers how to loop over a list

Comment: Literally a google search away http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> NEW_2 = [['ID', 'FK'], ['1', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['5', '3'], ['6', '2']]
>>> for cols in NEW_2:
...     print '{:5}{:5}'.format(*cols)
```

Prints:

```
ID   FK   
1    1    
2    1    
5    3    
6    2
```

Answer (score 0):

After all this time and better skills, I have a good and easy way to do that:

```
NEW_2 = [['ID', 'FK'], ['1', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['5', '3'], ['6', '2']]

for i in NEW_2:
    print i[0],i[1]
```