# How to print list elements (which are also lists) in separated lines in Python

Tags: python, list

I've checked the post and answers on the SO post [*Printing list elements on separated lines in Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python), while I think my problem is a different one.

What I want is to transform:

```
lsts = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

into the output like below:

```
[[1],
[1, 1],
[1, 2, 1],
[1, 3, 3, 1],
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

I tried append, print in the for loop
and "\n".join() but all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieven exactly what you want, you could manually unroll and print the outer array like already suggested:

```
>>> lsts = [[1], [2,3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> print("[" + ",\n".join(str(i) for i in lsts) + "]")
[[1],
[2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]]
```

Not exactly what you requested, but [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.dumps) can do some pretty-printing by specifying an `indent`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(lsts, indent=4))
[
    [
        1
    ],
    [
        2,
        3
    ],
    [
        4,
        5,
        6
    ]
]
```

And then there's [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint.pprint), which is intended for somewhat intelligent printing for humans:

```
>>> pprint(lsts, width=20)
[[1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Very enlightening! Thank you again Felk

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation of that same idea:

```
output = "[" + ",\n".join(str(i) for i in lsts) + "]"
```

Comment: the `[]` in the `join()` are unnecessary. A generator expression is faster and more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
print ']\n'.join(str(lsts).split('],'))
```

This is gross but does what you want it to.

```
for l in lsts:
    print l
```

almost does except you miss the first and last brackets. so you could do

```
list_len = len(lsts)
for i in range(list_len):
    if i == 0:
        print '['+str(lsts[i])
    elif i == list_len - 1:
        print str(lsts[i]( +']'
    else:
        print lists[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lsts = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
print('[',end='')
for i,value in enumerate(lsts):
    print(value,end='')
    if i == len(lsts)-1:
        print(']')
    else:
        print(',')
```

**Output:**

```
[[1],
[1, 1],
[1, 2, 1],
[1, 3, 3, 1],
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(lsts)):` is considered unpythonic. `for i, value in enumerate(lsts):` is the pretty way to go

Comment: @Felk - Thanks for pointing this out, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Ren, that's easy to conceive!

Comment: Thanks Felk, I didn't know enumerate() and always use range(len()) until just now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the form of lsts is fixed:

```
>>> print '['+'\n'.join([ str(i) for i in lsts ]) + ']'  

[[1]  
[1, 1]  
[1, 2, 1]  
[1, 3, 3, 1]  
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you Cui. It's better to add a comma here, making it more like a list of lists.  ',\n'.join()

Comment: Yes, it is that if you need a comma. Sorry to watch your reply so late.