# Iterating through multiple lists consecutively and printing the value for each list

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I have 5 lists and I want to iterate through each one, set it to a variable called current, so my output should be printing current, where current is the new list that is printed every time

```
One = [1,2,3]
Two = [4,5,6]
Three = [7,8,9]
Four = [10,11,12]
Five = [13,14,15]
```

Output:

> [1,2,3]
>
> [4,5,6]
>
> [7,8,9]
>
> [10,11,12]
>
> [13,14,15]

Comment: Post code you tried to solve the same.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why you need to save it to a variable called `current` if all you need is to print the lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print list elements (which are also lists) in separated lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490752/how-to-print-list-elements-which-are-also-lists-in-separated-lines-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should put them all in one big list and then loop through each of them:

```
big_list = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9],
           [10,11,12],
           [13,14,15]]

for current in big_list:
    print(current)
```

You can also use a more advanced feature: `join`. This will simplify the print statement:

```
big_list = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9],
           [10,11,12],
           [13,14,15]]

print('\n'.join([str(current) for current in big_list]))
```

Output of both:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: what if I want to return that value of current after every iteration but then go back into the loop and continue until every list in big_list is returned

Comment: What do you mean by return? In the sense of the python keyword `return`, you cannot go back to a `return` statement, and it wouldn't make sense to do so. Do you maybe mean that you want to call a function each time?

Comment: yeah I want to call the function each time and use the list of current for another operation, then continue the loop and update the list of current for the next operation

Comment: This you would simply call the function you define yourself by passing in `current`. My example does this already, because `print` is, in fact, a function. So just change `print` to `name_of_your_function` and define your function and you should be good.

Comment: Your advice helped and I was able to solve what I needed... Thank you bendl