# List vs generator comprehension speed with join function

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

So I got these examples from the official documentation. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

What exactly makes the first example (generator expression) slower than the second (list comprehension)?

```
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
0.8187260627746582
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])', number=10000)
0.7288308143615723
```

Comment: See Ray Hettinger's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python

Comment: @BhargavRao -- While I agree that Raymond's answer does address this question, this question is fundamentally different than _that_ question.  (Here, OP wants to know why list-comp is faster -- In the other question, OP didn't even know the difference between a generator or a list-comp...).  I guess I'm not sure what the policy should be for bringing the dupe-hammer down in cases like these ...

Comment: @mgilson The other question is a super set of this question. There was a post on meta that stated that we can vote to close as a duplicate of a broader question. Like for e.g, closing *how do I convert this to a list comprehension* as a duplicate of *what is a list comp, how does it work*. There are attempts at creating broader questions to help Ops (have a look at [cannon](http://sopython.com/canon/)). All in all, if a particular question has been answered somewhere else, then we close as dupe. (I'm against the description that says*exact dupe* for hammers instead of the normal has an answer)

Comment: If need be, we can re-close it as a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138661/my-list-comprehension-is-faster-than-equivalent-code-with-generator-expression) which again is the dupe of the original post.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `str.join` method converts its iterable parameter to a list if it's not a list or tuple already. This lets the joining logic iterate over the items multiple times (it makes one pass to calculate the size of the result string, then a second pass to actually copy the data).

You can see this in [the CPython source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l9821):

```
PyObject *
PyUnicode_Join(PyObject *separator, PyObject *seq)
{
    /* lots of variable declarations at the start of the function omitted */

    fseq = PySequence_Fast(seq, "can only join an iterable");

    /* ... */
}
```

The `PySequence_Fast` function in the C API does just what I described. It converts an arbitrary iterable into a list (essentially by calling `list` on it), unless it already is a list or tuple.

The conversion of the generator expression to a list means that the usual benefits of generators (a smaller memory footprint and the potential for short-circuiting) don't apply to `str.join`, and so the (small) additional overhead that the generator has makes its performance worse.