# How to strip the last comma in a string, when I am looping the comma to separate different part of it

Tags: python

I am trying to loop every element of a list, and append each element of the list to a string in the format like `aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ....`

My loop is like this:

```
    string = "" 

    for num in sorted(list):
       string = "xyz" + "-" + str(list[num])
       string = string + ", "

    return string
```

The format it output is like `xyz - 1, xyz - 3, xyz -6,`

How can I end up without last comma in a format like
`xyz - 1, xyz - 3, xyz -6` ?

Comment: `return string[:-2]`?

Comment: use `", ".join(list)` to concatenate elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constructing the string yourself, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join):

```
string = ', '.join("xyz-"+str(x) for x in sorted(list))
```

`.join` is called on a string that acts as a *separator*: it will be inserted between the elements (but not after the last element). In the `join` you need to provide an iterable (list, tuple, set, generator,...) that provides strings that should be joined together.

In this case we wrote an iterator that will, for every `x` in the `sorted(list)` generate a string `"xyz-"+str(x)` and these products will be joined together.

---

**ERRORS?**

There is furthermore probably an error in your code:

```
for num in sorted(list):
    string = "xyz" + "-" + str(list[num])
```

If you use a `for` over a list, you get the elements, not the indices. So it should be `num` instead of `list[num]`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

use `str.join` and a list comprehension to avoid doing this:

```
return ", ".join(["xyz-{}".format(num) for num in sorted(lst)])
```

(and note that your code has other issues than that: using `list` as a variable, doing `lst[num]` where `num` is needed are 2 examples)

(`([` is not a typo: creating a list comprehension and not a generator comprehension allows `join` to work faster: [List vs generator comprehension speed with join function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function))

Comment: Do you mean the return? It is a method which will be called in another class

Comment: No his suggestion in replacement of your code above.  Try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much!