# Python: string join multiple attributes from object

Tags: python, string, object, join, attributes

i have an orm based object list. i now want to concatenate some attributes delimited by the "|" (pipe) and then concatenate all objects by using "\n".

i tried:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

obj_list = [A("James", 42), A("Amy", "23")]
"\n".join("|".join(o.name, o.age for o in obj_list))

File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole Argument
```

what exactly must be parenthesized?

Any hints?

Tank you.

Comment: Here is a way just using `joins`: `'\n'.join(['|'.join([o.name, str(o.age)]) for o in obj_list])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to achieve:

```
obj_list = [A("James", 42), A("Amy", "23")]
"\n".join("|".join((o.name, o.age)) for o in obj_list)
```

Result:

```
James|42
Amy|23
```

Note: if your object contains non-string attributes, you have to convert those to strings, e.g. `"|".join(o.name, str(o.age))`.

Comment: Thank you. That is - for me - the second best way :)
can i use a join and a inner join, so i only have to add arguments if i want to increase them or do i have to add curly braces every time too?

Comment: what do you mean by second best way?

Comment: `join` is one of the times when it makes more sense to use a list comprehension in a function call.  When you give it a generator expression, it has to iterate through the expression and build a list anyways. [More](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/6779307)

Comment: Felix, when i use your code from above i get this result

TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: got that right now too :)

Thank you very much! --> SOLVED

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you're right, but since it speed difference isn't that high, I'd say that it doesn't matter in most cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function?noredirect=1&lq=1 for timing