# Replace multiple strings at the same time

Tags: python

Lets say I have this string "abcd"

Now I want to replace all 'a's with a 'd' and I want to replace all 'd's with an 'a'. The problem is that string.replace does not work in this situation.

"abcd".replace('a','d').replace('d','a')

> abca

Expected output is "dbca"

How would I acheive this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/multiple-character-replace-with-python

Comment: @HarshaW Similar, but not by a lot. Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.translate()`.

> Return a copy of the string in which each character has been mapped through the given translation table.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Example:

```
>>> "abcd".translate(str.maketrans("ad","da"))
'dbca'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to switch the values that you want

```
x = "abcd"
''.join(['d' if i == 'a' else 'a' if i == 'd' else i for i in x])
```

> 'dbca'

---

Without a list

```
x = "abcd"
''.join('d' if i == 'a' else 'a' if i == 'd' else i for i in x)
```

> 'dbca'

---

## Timing

```
In [1]: x = "abcd"*10000000

In [2]: %timeit ''.join('d' if i == 'a' else 'a' if i == 'd' else i for i in x)
5.78 s ± 152 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit ''.join(['d' if i == 'a' else 'a' if i == 'd' else i for i in x])
4.49 s ± 157 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It turns out the list comprehension is slightly faster.

Comment: You don't need the list, you can just use a comprehension.  Creating a list will always hurt performance

Comment: @chrisz what do you mean by "a comprehension"  here? List comprehensions create lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga he doesn't need the brackets, they hurt performance.  `''.join('d' if i == 'a' else 'a' if i == 'd' else i for i in x)` works perfectly fine.  I should have said, "you can just use a generator"

Comment: I may be completely wrong about this.  I just timed with a list and a generator and the list was twice as fast. hmm...

Comment: @JahKnows I was indeed wrong, list is better here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function  My apologies

Comment: No, actually, generally unless your list would be very large a list comprehension will beat or match a *generator expression*. In the particular case of passing to `str.join` a list is created under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try python replace recipe :

```
string_word="abcd"

data=list(string_word)
replace_index=list({j:i for j,i in enumerate(data) if i=='a' or i=='d'}.keys())

data[replace_index[0]],data[replace_index[1]]=data[replace_index[1]],data[replace_index[0]]

print("".join(data))
```

output:

```
dbca
```