# How to add two strings by index

Tags: python, string, function, slice, indices

I tried many times but could not do it.

Here is an example:

```
print( concat_corresponding( "12345", "6789XYZ" ) )
```

Desired output:

```
162738495XYZ
```

Comment: show us what you've tried...show us `concat_corresponding` code. Is `162738495XYZ` the expected output or what you're getting?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

a = "12345"
b = "6789XYZ"

res = ''.join(list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))))

# '162738495XYZ'
```

Note the list conversion is not required, but [improves performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/9209546).

Answer (score 2):

You can levarege list comprehensions, join and zip:

```
te1 = "12345"
te2 = "6789XYZ"

print (''.join( ''.join(x) for x in zip(te1,te2)) + (te1[len(te2):] if len(te1)>len(te2) else te2[len(te1):]))
                                                    # ^^^^ this part adds the remainer of longer list to result
```

output:

```
162738495XYZ
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Explanation:

zip pairs up the characters by position, the rest makes the list of pairs back into a string.

Zip only works for the shorter length string - you can switch to itertools.zip_longest ([see JimDennis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50068970/7505395)) or append the longer lists part (like I did here)

[itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: This cuts off YZ since the strings are of different lengths.

Comment: Yeah, need to either zip up the slices that can be matched (and then append a slice from the longer one ... or use something like *itertools.izip_longest()* and munge the None values into empty strings (see my answer).

Comment: @WStokvis fixed that

Comment: @JimDennis thanks for the comment, was just editing that ;)#

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
''.join(['%s%s' % (x ,y)\
         for x,y in izip_longest("12345","6789XYZ", fillvalue='')])

## Was: ''.join(['%s%s' % (x if x else '',y if y else '') \
##         for x,y in izip_longest("12345","6789XYZ")])
```

To break that down a bit:

- the builtin *zip()* function zips only to the shorter of the two sequences; so we use *izip_longest()* from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) standard library module
- *izip_longest()* pads the generated sequences with *None* by default; so we add the *fillvalue=''* optional (keyword) argument
- the resulting substrings are all just joined together to form your results.

Comment: You can simply give `''` as fillvalue: [itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) no need to munge

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution is a little cleaner and takes advantage of the `fillvalue` keyword argument for [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
from itertools import zip_longest 

''.join(a+b for a, b in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is basic but useful

```
str1="12345"
str2="6789XYZ"
str3=""
i=0
for i, ch in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)):
    str3 += ch[0] + ch[1]

if len(str1) < len(str2):
    str3 += str2[i+1:]
else:
    str3 += str1[i+1:]
print(str3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is the following:

```
def concat_corresponding(string1, string2):
    minimum, maximum = sorted([string1, string2], key=len)
    return "".join(string1[i]+string2[i] for i in range(len(minimum))) + maximum[len(minimum):]

print(concat_corresponding( "12345", "6789XYZ" ))
```

Output:

```
162738495XYZ
```