# Performance of map vs generator expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, generator, map-function

I was doing a Python exercise to find all of the even numbers between two values. I came up with the following result

```
','.join(str(i) for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0)
```

But then I noticed it was a bit slower than using a `map`

```
In [105]: %timeit ','.join(str(i) for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop

In [107]: %timeit ','.join(map(str, (i for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 374 µs per loop
```

Researching this, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/5491375) which explains that when using a generator expression in a `join`

> The conversion of the generator expression to a list means that the usual benefits of generators (a smaller memory footprint and the potential for short-circuiting) don't apply to str.join, and so the (small) additional overhead that the generator has makes its performance worse.

This would suggest to me that casting a `map` to a `list` is faster than casting a generator

```
In [109]: %timeit list(map(str, (i for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 366 µs per loop

In [110]: %timeit list(str(i) for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 µs per loop
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: You're missing the list comp: `','.join([str(i) for i in range(1000, 3000+1) if i % 2 == 0])`

Comment: I think it is a bit __wanting__ to ask why map performs a few microseconds faster per loop than a generator.

Comment: But I would look at [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) for a pretty thorough breakdown

Comment: @d_kennetz, great in-depth response. thanks for pointing me there!