# what is a good way to combine list values to string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a source like this

```
address = ['63-1','STREET APT #3F','','NY']
```

I wanna this list to string like "63-1 STREET APT #3F NY"

some value in list is often empty.
What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: simple way is `' '.join([x for x in address if x])` ?

Comment: "Hacky" way: `' '.join(filter(None, address))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter out the empty strings, then simply `join` by `' '`.

```
>>> address = ['63-1','STREET APT #3F','','NY']
>>> ' '.join(filter(None, address))
'63-1 STREET APT #3F NY'
```

`filter(None, Iterable)` will filter out all [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) values. In a list of strings, only the empty string is falsy.

Answer (score 1):

I like list comprehensions and generator expressions:

```
>>> address = ['63-1','STREET APT #3F','','NY']
>>> ' '.join(s for s in address if s)
'63-1 STREET APT #3F NY'
>>> ' '.join([s for s in address if s])
'63-1 STREET APT #3F NY'
```

But note, that using a list comprehension is the fastest way, as `str.join` converts the argument to a list if it isn't already, which adds a layer of overhead for everything other than a list.

Comment: Interestingly, the second version [is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/3620003). First one looks nicer, though.

Comment: @timgeb Because generators (Python iterators) are slower than list comprehensions (tight C loops).

Comment: `join` is also a special case of needing a list anyway.