# Is there a more efficent way to extend a string?

Tags: python, string, loops

Does anybody know of a more efficent way to extend a string, eg `fred`, to be the length of the string `plaintext` - so that `fred` would become `fredfredf` - than this?

```py
# key='fred', msg='plaintext'?

def keypad(key, msg):
    while len(key) < len(msg):
        key += key
    key = key[:len(msg)]
    return key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No import needed, creates as few things as possible. Might be better then [Austins solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535555/7505395) (no imports, longer sourcecode):

```
key='fred'
msg='plaintext'

def keypad(key, msg):
    lk = len(key)
    lm = len(msg) 
    return ''.join( [ key[idx%lk] for idx in range(lm) ] )

print(keypad(key,msg))
# fredfredf
```

Leveraging the modulo division on the `key`-text in combination with a list (`.join()` would convert the generator to a list internally anyway - so faster to use a list in the first place - cudos to @Austin's comment).

Advantage:

- no imports
- no string slicing
- uses generator, so no intermediate string creations (just one at the end)
- no overshooting to be sliced away

---

Suggested read:

[List vs generator comprehension speed with join function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function) for speed of `join()` for list vs generator

Comment: +1. Good one, but I would replace that generator to a list comp. `join` with a list comp is faster than with a generator.

Comment: @Austin you keep telling me that, and I forgetting it. Ups. Added.

Comment: Lol. Glad, you still remember my words. :)

Comment: @Austing even found the reference for it ;)

Comment: Seems this is the only solution currently not already covered by the dupe target.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**`islice`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) + [**`cycle`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

key = 'fred'
msg = 'plaintext'

print(''.join(islice(cycle(key), len(msg))))
# fredfredf
```

Answer (score 2):

```
key='fred'
msg='plaintext'
key = key*(len(msg)//len(key) + 1) 
print(key[:len(msg)]) 
#fredfredf
```

---

Or

```
print((key*(len(msg)//len(key) + 1))[:len(msg)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Less good then Austins solution, but better then yours:

Your approach is inefficient because you

- concat strings: the old one is destroyed and a new one created (over and over)
- you double the length of your combined string on each iteration (might get huge overshoot)

It would be better to calculate how often 
`key` fits into `msg` and create only one resulting string (reducing the amount of created/destroyed strings) and also reducing the size of  the resulting string.

```
key='fred'
msg='plaintext'

def keypad(key, msg):
    l=len(msg)               # store loally  so you do not call len twice on it
    mult = l//len(key) + 1
    return (key*mult)[:l]    # overshoots maximally by len(k)-1 characters

print(keypad(key,msg))
```

Strings created for:

```
key = "1234"
msg = "1234567890123456789"
```

we create

```
"12341234"                         # you, created, thrown away
"1234123412341234"                 # you, created, thrown away
"12341234123412341234123412341234" # you

"12341234123412341234"             # me
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use
  [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to
  compute the number of full repetitions needed, and the number of
  extra characters.

```py
   def keypad(key, msg):
     wanted = len(msg)
     a, b = divmod(wanted, len(key))
     return key * a + key[:b]
```

*or*

To repeat a string until it's at least as long as the length you want.

- You calculate the appropriate number of repeats and put it on the
  right-hand side of that multiplication operator.
- Then, you can trim it to the exact length you want with an array
  slice:

```py
   def keypad(key, msg):
     length = len(msg)
     return (key * (int(length/len(key))+1))[:length]
```