# How to turn a list of integers to a single integer?

Tags: python

I have list that contains **only integers**. I want it to be a full single integer.
Such that I have list like this:

```
[500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
500400300200100
```

Where is what I have tried:

```
ls = [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
new_ls = []
for i in range(len(ls)):
    new_ls.append(str(ls[i]))

integer = int(''.join(new_ls))
print(integer)
```

Note that: `join()` doesn't work for list which contains integer(at least this is what I know). For that I am first turning the list to string then joining.
Is there any shorter way for this?

Comment: `print(int("".join(map(str, [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]))))` ?

Comment: What's the use-case for this?

Comment: @KlausD. Not anything specific. Just exploring stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
integer = int(''.join([str(x) for x in ls]))
```

Comment: You don't need to create a temporary list: `integer = int(''.join(str(x) for x in ls))` would work just fine. This is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the hint. But I dont see the advantage of a generator in this example. Can you give some short explanation to this?

Comment: @martineau AFAIK, `str.join` is [one of the few exceptions where making a container is actually better than genexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function)

Comment: It avoids creating a temporary list whose only purpose is to be passed to `join()` as an argument. If `ls` is short it probably doesn't make much difference (unless it done millions of times).

Comment: @Chris: That may not apply in this case because `str()` has to be called either way. The only definitive test would be to `timeit`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
lst = [500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
result = int(''.join(list(map(str, lst))))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
500400300200100
```