# Pythonic way to join a string in a loop to create textblock

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

Is there a pythonic way to join a string in a loop to create a block of text?

Example:

```
for x in range(4):
    content = f'{x}[block]'
    content+content

print(content)
```

Desired outcome:

```
0[block]
1[block]
2[block]
3[block]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to join your block strings by newlines:

```
print("\n".join(f"{x}[block]" for x in range(4)))
```

Or for faster performance, use a [*list comprehension*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) instead:

```
print("\n".join([f"{x}[block]" for x in range(4)]))
```

<sup>See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function/37782238#37782238) for more information on why the second approach is faster than the first</sup>

Additionally, you could also append each block string to a list and join them at the end:

```
blocks = []
for x in range(4):
    blocks.append(f"{x}[block]")

print("\n".join(blocks))
```

If we want to simply print each block string without joining by newlines, we can make use of the `sep` keyword from [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(*(f"{x}[block]" for x in range(4)), sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
0[block]
1[block]
2[block]
3[block]
```