# How to add a comma between each number when generated?

Tags: python

```
numbers = []
for i in range(2000, 3201):
   if (i % 7) == 0 and (i % 5) !=0:
       numbers.append(i)

numbers = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in numbers])

print(numbers)
```

**When printed, it doesn't have commas between the numbers. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leave the `numbers` list as is, without joining anything, and directly unpack the list inside of `print()` invocation:

```
print(*numbers, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(2000, 3201):
   if (i % 7) == 0 and (i % 5) !=0:
       numbers.append(i)

numbers = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in numbers])

print(numbers)
```

Comment: I understand that there are better methods, this is just the closest solution to the questions askers attempted method. If you have a different method you should list it with the other answers to give the question asker a better scope of the different ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @DemianWolf Actually, it is better to pass `list` instead of generator because `str.join` would convert it into list anyway. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function