# How to extract each word consecutive to its own previous number in a string and sorting the result in Python

Tags: python

Input  : x3b4U5i2
Output : bbbbiiUUUUUxxx

How can i solve this problem in Python. I have to print the word next to it's number n times and sort it

Comment: Can you have more than 9 repeats? Are the characters to repeat always letters?

Answer (score 0):

One option, extract the character/digit(s) pairs with a regex, sort them by letter (ignoring case), multiply the letter by the number of repeats, join:

```
s = 'x3b4U5i2'

import re

out = ''.join([c*int(i) for c,i in 
               sorted(re.findall('(\D)(\d+)', s),
                      key=lambda x: x[0].casefold())
              ])

print(out)
```

Output: `bbbbiiUUUUUxxx`

If you want to handle multiple characters you can use `'(\D+)(\d+)'`

Comment: @CryptoFool I just noticed that as well reading the question again to proof my answer. It is fixed ;)

Comment: You can provide a generator expression to `str.join` rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: @Chris yes but [it's less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function) as `join` requires to know the length of the input

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the formatting will always be `<char><int>` with `<int>` being in between 1 and 9...

```
input_ = "x3b4U5i2"

result_list = [input_[i]*int(input_[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(input_), 2)]
result_list.sort(key=str.lower)
result = ''.join(result_list)
```

There's probably a much more performance-oriented approach to solving this, it's just the first solution that came into my limited mind.

## Edit

After the feedback in the comments I've tried to improve performance by sorting it first, but I have actually decreased performance in the following implementaiton:

```
input_ = "x3b4U5i2"

def sort_first(value):
    return value[0].lower()

tuple_construct = [(input_[i], int(input_[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(input_), 2)]
tuple_construct.sort(key=sort_first)
result = ''.join([tc[0] * tc[1] for tc in tuple_construct])
```

Execution time for 100,000 iterations on it:

```
1) The execution time is: 0.353036
2) The execution time is: 0.4361724
```

Comment: Since you mention performance, the drawback of your approach is that you generate first the expanded string **then** sort. Sorting being being O(n*logn), this makes it more expensive than sorting before. ;)

Comment: Also, no need to convert your string to `ord`, python knows how to sort strings :)

Comment: For your comparison to be meaningful you need to test **large** inputs. The O(n*logn) complexity has an impact when n is large. For small inputs it's negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear if multiple digit counts or groups of letters should be handled.  Here's a solution that does all of that:

```
import re

def main(inp):
    parts = re.split(r"(\d+)", inp)
    parts_map = {parts[i]:int(parts[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(parts)-1, 2)}
    print(''.join([c*parts_map[c] for c in sorted(parts_map.keys(),key=str.lower)]))

main("x3b4U5i2")
main("x3brx4U5i2")
main("x23b4U35i2")
```

Result:

```
bbbbiiUUUUUxxx
brxbrxbrxbrxiiUUUUUxxx
bbbbiiUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: This is more or less my approach except that the use of a dictionary intermediate would make it fail on input like `'x3b1x2'` ;) NB. I considered single chars myself but using `'(\D+)(\d+)'` would make it work with multichar as you did.

Answer (score 0):

No list comprehensions or generator expressions in sight. Just using `re.sub` with a lambda to expand the length encoding, then sorting that, and then joing that back into a string.

```
import re

s = "x3b4U5i2"

''.join(sorted(re.sub(r"(\D+)(\d+)", 
                      lambda m: m.group(1)*int(m.group(2)), 
                      s),
        key=lambda x: x[0].casefold()))
# 'bbbbiiUUUUUxxx'
```

---

*If* we use `re.findall` to extract a list of pairs of strings and multipliers:

```
import re

s = 'x3b4U5i2'

pairs = re.findall(r"(\D+)(\d+)", s)
```

Then we can use some functional style to sort that list before expanding it.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def compose(f, g): 
  return lambda x: f(g(x))

sorted(pairs, key=compose(str.lower, itemgetter(0)))
# [('b', '4'), ('i', '2'), ('U', '5'), ('x', '3')]
```

Comment: Same remark than to @EduGord, if the expanded string is much larger than the original, it's quite less efficient to sort after. Simple example on `x100000a100000`.

Comment: That's completely fair. Your approach was the first thing to come to my mind, but there'd be no point in posting the same answer twice.