# Using the title() method with a list

Tags: python, list, title

In Python how the title() method can be used?

Is it only for a single item or also for a whole list?

The first print works, the second returns an error. Why?

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'whale', 'koala', 'panda']
print(f"\nname of the 3rd animal: {animals[2].title()}")
print(f"\nname of all animals: {animals.title()}")
```

The first print works, the second returns an error. Why?

Comment: *"Why?"* — Because `title` is a method on string objects, not list objects.

Comment: You can apply it to all the strings in the list. And join them together: `", ".join(map(str.title, animals))`

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) doesn't have a [`title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method. You need to loop over the elements.

One option is to use a list comprehension:

```
print(f"name of all animals: {', '.join([a.title() for a in animals])}")
```

Output:

```
name of all animals: Dog, Cat, Whale, Koala, Panda
```

###### timings for the aficionados

```
# list_comp
', '.join([a.title() for a in l])

# generator
', '.join(a.title() for a in l)

# map_generator
', '.join(map(str.title, l))

# map_list
', '.join(list(map(str.title, l)))

# join_title
', '.join(l).title()
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, the `[]` are superfluous…

Comment: @deceze they are not, [`join` is more efficient on a list than a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function) (it requires to know the size of the iterable). I agree it would work without the brackets but I put them on purpose ;)

Comment: Curious @mozway, if map was used like in my comment, wouldn't it have a `length_hint`? Would it be more efficient to use map and list or the comprehension?

Comment: Fair enough, I'd still probably write it without. :o)

Comment: @Jab `', '.join(list(map(str.title, animals)))` is a bit more efficient than `', '.join([a.title() for a in animals])` and `', '.join(map(str.title, animals))` in a test on 6M items.

Comment: Just realized `', '.join(animals).title()` would actually be the most efficient and actually more readable.

Comment: @Jab yes that's true, good one! (but OP should be aware that this only works because of this particular method)

Comment: @Jab yes, in the case of join+title specifically, because of how title works. But I think everyone here tries to make it more general/keep it as a list until the very end because no details from OP. :)

Comment: Since there was some info about "more efficient": the difference is really small. Since @mozway mentioned test on 6M items, I did my own of similar size (10M, each of length 100 - just did `my_list = [string.printable] * 10000000` because I'm lazy) and the time difference depends more on what my machine is doing than on type of the iterable passed to join (I had map be 11.25s once and 13.12s another time). One would need to time and average a lot of runs to actually determine which is faster. (timeit by default wants to do 1M runs)

Comment: "It doesn't work because list doesn't have a title method." thanks

Comment: as I was finishing the above comment, @mozway uploaded the graph - please explain how many repetitions you did to make it comparable

Comment: @h4z3 the x-axis is the number of items in the list, the y-axis is the runtime. I think perfplot only runs once each combination, but the fact that it tests many combinations enables to see non-dependent variability (=noise). I also tested with `%%timeit`, which makes between 7 and 100,000 repetitions and observed a significant (but small) difference.