# Python - remove space between the strings

Tags: python

I have string array which looks like below,

```
THIS IS TO TEST                                                            &#32;
USING    APPLE                                                             &#32;
ENTER A  LINK                                                              &#32;
```

I need to remove the spaces from the string, so that final string will be like

```
THIS IS TO TEST USING    APPLE ENTER A  LINK
```

I Tried below code

```
for s in htmljob_arr:
    s = s.replace("&#32;","")
    s = s.strip() + " "
    final_htmljob_str += s
```

Is there any better approach to remove the space between the strings?

Comment: What exactly is `htmljob_arr`? A list? A file? I assume it's not a NumPy array...

Comment: `# Define the string to be processed in entry variable.

delimiter = " " # Define the delimiter: 60 consecutive spaces.
output = entry.replace(delimiter * 60, "") # Replace that consecutive spaces with nothing.
output = output.replace("&#32;", "") # You have something at the end to remove.
output = output.replace("\n", " ") # Replace all new lines with space.

print(output) # Print the output.`

Comment: @nycaff That looks like an answer, and is pretty hard to read without line breaks. Also judging by the asker's code, I don't think the original input is one big string.

Comment: Try: strg = """THIS IS TO TEST                                                            &#32;
USING    APPLE                                                             &#32;
ENTER A  LINK"""

print(" ".join(strg.replace('&#32;','').split()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.join`:

```
" ".join([s.replace("&#32;","").strip() for s in htmljob_arr])
```

Result

```
THIS IS TO TEST USING    APPLE ENTER A  LINK
```

Or for extra credit using `re`:

```
re.sub("\s*&#32;", "", " ".join(htmljob_arr))
```

Comment: Just to make it perfect, there's no need to create an actual list. You can remove `[]` to use "generator comprehension".

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Using a list comprehension is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function) when using join

Comment: Beware of premature optimization, guys. This code isn't sending rockets to the moon. It's usually more confusing to inundate new users with all these clever solutions.

Comment: This isn't confusing as i see it. Perfectly readable imho

Comment: I think you don’t need: lfor s in htmljob_arr])”, replace in string and strip() is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the format of your list:

```py
strings = [
"THIS IS TO TEST                                                            &#32;",
"USING    APPLE                                                             &#32;",
"ENTER A  LINK                                                              &#32;"]
```

We can use list comprehension to remove the extra characters and leave it in a list format:

```py
cleaned_strings = [s.replace('&#32;', '').strip() for s in strings]

# Result: ['THIS IS TO TEST', 'USING    APPLE', 'ENTER A  LINK']
```