# list of tuple for csv compatible format in python

Tags: python

need to format list of tuples to load csv (convert to string) file.

My input:

```
my_content = [('unq_id1','unq_id2','unq_id3'),
 ('2020-07-01','O-001','8.12'),
 (None,'O-02','7.32')]
```

Expected output:

```
'unq_id1,unq_id2,unq_id3\n2020-07-01,O-001,8.12\nNone,O-002,7.32'
```

I tried with below code and it is working fine but I need to generalize the script if I get more records to handle like till `{tup[99]}`.

My code:

```
my_content = '\n'.join(f'{tup[0]},{tup[1]},{tup[2]}' for tup in my_content)
```

Comment: try `my_content = '\n'.join(",".join(tup) for tup in my_content)`

Comment: from csv or to csv?

Comment: List to string for csv load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through tuple elements in your generator expression using the additional for loop. Also you can use the ternary operator inside it to check the `None` values. Like this:

```py
csv_string = '\n'.join(','.join([element if element else 'None' for element in tup])
                                                                for tup in my_content)
```

Output:

```py
>>> csv_string
'unq_id1,unq_id2,unq_id3\n2020-07-01,O-001,8.12\nNone,O-02,7.32'
```

Comment: HI @Vitaly Kovalev, For `None` type your code is working, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just `join` inside the join statement

```
my_content = '\n'.join([",".join(tup) for tup in my_content])
```

result:

```
>>> my_content
'unq_id1,unq_id2,unq_id3\n2020-07-01,O-001,8.12\n2020-07-04,O-02,7.32'
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the list comprehension when you could just pass a generator to join? i.e., *'\n'.join(','.join(e) for e in my_content)*

Comment: getting `sequence item 3: expected str instance, NoneType found` error

Comment: @RSG your data is not the same as the input in that case

Comment: @DarkKnight it's considered faster as `join` needs to know the size anyway, so it's better to pass a container where size can be retrieved, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you are right. My actual data contains `None` data for few of tuples. That's the reason why it is not working your code. `None` case is working with code I mentioned above.

Comment: Edited the input data in Question