# How do you take a nested list and display it in curses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I want to take a list like this

```
mylist = [['_','X','_'],['X','_','_'],['X','_','_']]
```

and display it like this:

```
_ X _
X _ _
X _ _
```

would I use 2 nested loops and build a string?

```
mystring=''
for line in mylist:
   for char in line:
       mystring += char + ' '
   mystring += '\n'
screen.addstr(mystring,0,0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing list elements on separated lines in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
mylist = [['_','X','_'],['X','_','_'],['X','_','_']]

mystring = '\n'.join(' '.join(sublist) for sublist in mylist)

screen.addstr(mystring,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [str.join](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiU6pCkzYPSAhUEp48KHcIDBnkQFggeMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1876191%2Fexplain-python-join&usg=AFQjCNEINa8hMth6ucTQUDQbiUCqGxo2Mw&sig2=ZcjVlP2W4XU3zO5lg6AEZg&bvm=bv.146496531,d.c2I) :

```
for i in mylist :
    print ''.join(i)
```

If you want spaces between the characters, replace `''` by a whitespace `' '`.