# I am trying to add a new line to a list when I print it but I can't make it work

Tags: python, list, newline

I had been trying to do it like when I add a new line to a normal statement but it doesn't work if I do it like that.

```
cars = ["audi", "bmw", "toyota"]
print(\ncars)
```

It shows this error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

How does one add a new line to a printed list? Btw I am a beginner to python and programming in general.

Comment: `print(cars)` should do, and it automatically adds a newline. Also look at the documentation of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: print("\n".join(cars)) This was answered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Are you trying to print each element of the list on a single line?

Comment: Riccardo Bucco No. I just wanted there to be a new line before the printed list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
print("\n",cars)
```

write backslash n, instead of slash n

Answer (score 0):

`print("\n".join(cars))`

This was answered already here:

[Printing list elements on separated lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
print("\n"+cars)
```

That's the correct way to do it.
You need to write backslash n, not forward slash n

Comment: It shouldn't, show me your code. Also, just simply printing should also do the trick

Comment: @CoderCharmander I would love to but I'm on my mobile and I don't use stack on here often, so could you tell me how to accept your edit?

Comment: I don't know. (I am also on mobile)

Comment: @snakecharmerb sorry, missed my quotations

Comment: @CoderCharmander I found where I messed up, my bad. As I said, I'm on mobile so I didn't check my code beforehand... Cockiness is problematic, isn't it 