# Python code not displaying the list values each in a new line no matter how hard I try

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I've written a code which works pretty well, no errors, no problems. But no matter how hard I try to print the list values each in a new line, it still wouldn't work. I've tried `sep='\n'`, and even tried to put the list in a loop to print each value one by one. I still get the result printed all in a row, in one line. This sounds too annoying and I can't figure out why my code is having this strange behavior. Here's my code:

```
length = int(input())
input_string = [int(y) for y in input().split()]

def lowest(string):

    return(min(x for x in string if x is not None))

def none_set(string):
    for k in range(length):
        if string[k] != None:
            if string[k] <=0:
                string[k] = None

def counter(string):
    nums = 0
    for h in range(length):
        if string[h] != None:
            nums += 1

    return nums

cnt = []

for i in range(length):   
    minimum = lowest(input_string)
    none_set(input_string) 
    
    cnt.append(counter(input_string))

    for j in range(length):
        if input_string[j] != None:
            input_string[j] -= minimum
        
result = list(set(cnt))[::-1]
print(result, sep='\n') #Doesn't print the values in new line :/
```

**Sample Input:**

```
6
5 4 4 2 2 8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
6
4
2
1
```

**The Output I Get:**

```
[6, 4, 2, 1]
```

In case you want to know what exactly my code does, check this link [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks/problem) (No login/signup needed), however, the issue is not really relative to what the goal of my code is, I'd say.

I appreciate in advance, for any tip, solution, or help.

Comment: `for x in result: print(x)` should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing list elements on separated lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167731/printing-list-elements-on-separated-lines-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're printing the whole list.

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
```

If I print this list I get `['a','b','c']`. To print each item you can use a for loop like so:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']

for item in lst:
    print(item)

#output: 
a
b
c
```

Comment: Right, but why does ```sep='\n'``` work then?

Comment: oops, my bad, yes, I meant why does ```sep='\n'``` NOT work.

Comment: Gotcha. Well @Eitan  Rosati Explained it for you I see :). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print like that:

```
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you :)) Now it works. But I still don't understand why ```sep='\n'``` would not work. Is it not supposed to be used in such cases?

Comment: Because when you print a list he consider the list as one object.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you:))

Comment: List have a default function to show him as a string. because list like any other data structer in python is an well defind object

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 for i in result:
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join()` instead of multiple calls to `print()`. Some will consider it more difficult to read, but it's definitely more efficient even for small lists, and orders of magnitude faster for lists greater than 100 elements.

```py
print("\n".join(map(str, result)))
```